# Spring security : Why adding the JWT filter before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working with  Spring security and jwt ,but there is something that i don't understand in the configuration file (same configuration in all tutorials on JWT )
it is why to add the Custom jwt filter before the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` since i already have a public  authentication controller based on username and password  in somewhere of the project and why not adding it in some other order ?

```
@Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((AuthenticationEntryPoint) unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore((Filter) authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR;**

I believe it's just a random filter someone on the internet happened to have chosen and shared his/her code somewhere, and it's been adopted that way ever since.

---

**For the curious**

I personally went through the Spring Security source code and found out that the filters in Spring application context with their respective `@Order`s are as below:

```
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter -> 100
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter -> 300
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter -> 400
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter -> 500
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter -> 600
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter -> 700
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter -> 800
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter -> 900
org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter -> 1000
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter -> 1100
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter -> 1200
org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter -> 1300
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter -> 1400
org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter -> 1500
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter -> 1600
org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter -> 1800
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter -> 1900
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter -> 2000
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter -> 2100
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter -> 2200
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter -> 2300
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter -> 2400
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter -> 2500
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter -> 2600
org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter -> 2700
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter -> 2800
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter -> 2900
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter -> 3000
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter -> 3100
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter -> 3200
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor -> 3300
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter -> 3400
```

**Please note that the less the order value, the more prioritized the filter.**

But these are all the filters that Spring registers. Spring Security on the other hand, being a single filter chain containing a number of filters inside, includes only some of these, which are (in priority order):

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

You can get this list by setting the debug flag to true in the Spring Security config by

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

---

**Where to put the custom Jwt Filter ?**

I'd personally place the custom Jwt Filter right after `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and before `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, forming below chain:

```
  Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
                            <------ Here's where the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter 
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  JwtAuthTokenFilter        <------   Here's your filter.
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

You see the motivation in doing so, is to let Spring security exception handler resides in `ExceptionTranslatorFilter` to handle your exception as is.
Because if you place your filter where the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` would be, any possible exception thrown by your filter will not be seen by the `ExceptionTranslatorFilter`, instead it will go all the way back to the `throwable()` method of Tomcat's `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve`, (if you're using Tomcat as the servlet impl., obviously), and what it is going to do is, **redirect your request to the default error path, i.e. `/error`.**

Here's where the fun begins; upon an exception thrown by your filter that is supposed to intercept whatever request coming into your application (say `/hello`), now a subsequent request to the predefined error path (let's assume `/error`) will be made. And by luck, if you haven't happened to "permit" that path with your `HttpSecurity` config, what's next is below series of events:

1. The same security chain will be applied to the *new* request with requestURI `/error`
2. If your custom filter extends `OncePerRequestFilter`, which I assume it would, it will NOT BE FILTERED AGAIN, since it would have been marked as FILTERED in the previous pass.
3. The rest of the filter chain will be invoked in the same order above all the way to the last filter, a.k.a `FilterSecurityInterceptor`
4. It'll evaluate the authentication token, pull in the `AccessDecisionVoter`s, which will promptly vote the unfamiliar `/error` request as unauthenticated, throw an `AccessDeniedException` and call it a day.
5. The very next filter on the way back to the client, which is no other than `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will see this `AccessDeniedException`, will evaluate it as a regular access denial and call the `AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence` with the `AccessDeniedException` being the 3rd parameter.
6. From then I would assume your code will call `sendError` within that method, and your client will receive this as a response.

So what's wrong with that, I blocked the request in my filter and the client got the error response ?

What's wrong is, the message client got, was not generated for your request or your error, it was generated for a request to the `/error` path and an error generated by the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`.

---

**So what should you do ?**

I would humbly suggest that, put your `JwtAuthTokenFilter` between the last two filters in the security filter chain, and the error you might throw will be handled by default spring security error resolver and you will save the server a roundtrip between the `StandardHostValve` and the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`.

```
http.addFilterAfter(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
```

Or don't and the client will get an error eventually.

Comment: this is one of the most understandable explanation of Security I have read.

Comment: I would like to mark this as my first bookmark answer in SOF. There are too many copiers and they don't know exactly what is happen, especially it related to Security section. 1 vote, gj @alegria

Comment: Thanks to you both guys, I am glad it was helpful to someone :)

Comment: excellent explanation!!!!! TOP